# Slack mentions in golang templates

Tags: go, gitlab, slack

I am using [go gitlab](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/xanzy/go-gitlab?utm_source=godoc#BasicUser) package to fetch users from gitlab. While trying to tag a person in slack in my go template using the following syntax `@{{.Name}}` , Slack receives a string `@Foo Bar`, but the person is not actually being tagged. Are there any workarounds available? [Here's the screenshot of slack output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwmOc.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code (the code producing the Slack message).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the details mentioned in the question.

You are using `@{{.Name}}`.

`@SlackId` should be used to tag a user instead of `@UserName`

To tag a user for mentions, *you will need their ***Slack ID****